# Magento 2.4, How to autofill value of Page Builder/textarea instead of Page Builder(form details) initialized as blank

Tags: magento2, patches, setup, eav-attributes, page-builder

In admin Catalog->Category->content

[image]

I would like this Form detail:Page Builder to have Layout->Row and Element->HTML Code="Default Value" at setup.

[image]

```
<?php

namespace Justins\Myapp\Setup\Patch\Data;

use Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetup;
use Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\ModuleDataSetupInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Setup\Patch\DataPatchInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Category;

class AddFeatureDescription implements DataPatchInterface
{

    const ATTRIBUTE_CODE = 'show_form_detail';

    private $moduleDataSetup;

    private $eavSetupFactory;

    private $logger;

    public function __construct(
        ModuleDataSetupInterface $moduleDataSetup,
        EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->moduleDataSetup = $moduleDataSetup;
        $this->eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public static function getDependencies(): array
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function getAliases(): array
    {
        return [];
    }

    public function apply()
    {
        try {
            $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $this->moduleDataSetup]);
            $eavSetup->addAttribute(Category::ENTITY, self::ATTRIBUTE_CODE, [
                'type' => 'text',
                'label' => 'Description',
                'input' => 'textarea',
                'required' => false,
                'sort_order' => 4,
                'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_STORE,
                'wysiwyg_enabled' => true,
                'is_html_allowed_on_front' => true,
                'group' => 'General Information',
            ]);
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $this->logger->error($e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible by the patch for the you need to use plug or observer to save a content while you create new category from the admin panel.

Here are the steps you need to follow.

**Step 1**

vendor/module/etc/adminhtml/events.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_category_prepare_save">
        <observer name="add_content_before_save_category" instance="vendor\module\Observer\SaveCategoryContentObserver" />
    </event>
</config>
```

**Step 2**

vendor/module/Observer/SaveCategoryContentObserver

```
<?php

namespace vendor\module\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;

class SaveCategoryContentObserver implements ObserverInterface
{

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $category = $observer->getEvent()->getCategory();
        $category->setData('description', $block->getContent());
        
        return $this;
    }
}
```